# Handlebars & Backbone - backbone html not rendering correctly

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am working on using Handlebars in backbone instead of underscore.  I do run into an issue with the rendered template not appending to the actual element I designate.

Model:

```
ImageApp.Models.Image = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    imagePath: '',
    description: 'No description available',
    postedOn: ''
    }
});
```

View:

```
 ImageApp.Views.ImageView = Backbone.View.extend({
 tagName: 'ul',

 initialize: function() {
     this.render();  
 },

 render: function() {
     var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#imageList-template').html());
     var renderedTemplate = compiledTemplate(this.model.toJSON());

     this.$el.html(renderedTemplate);

    $('#imageList').html(this.el);
 }
});
```

Template

```
<script id="imageList-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <li>
        <img src='{{imagePath}}' title='{{description}} />
    </li>
</script>
```

I would expect this to produce a unordered list with a single item containing a img element, but instead all it creates is an empty list item.  Any one see anything glaring I am doing wrong?

Comment: 2 things (possibly minor) - 1) You did not include the model, so you may have a typo in the properties, 2) You are missing a closing single quote after `{{description}}` that may possibly break the template.

Comment: @jesus.tesh lol it was the single quote...WOW... move it to a anwser and I will accept it, thanks!

Comment: You have mismatched `{}` in your example model.

Comment: @loganfsmyth that was a typo, thanks.

Comment: @Justin I figured, just wanted to make sure the question was clear. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing single quote after {{description}} that may possibly break the template.

**Moved to answer per request**
*(I don't have the ability to move the comment to a question)*